# Removing CTabFolder outline using CSS in Eclipse 4

Tags: css, eclipse-rcp, e4

I would like to style CTabFolder using CSS for which I would like to remove the unnecessary outline. My case is similar to the example used by Lars Vogel for CSS styling tutorial:

[Example Eclipse 4 application with CTabItem outline](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4CSS/images/theme40.png)

In this example I would like to remove the outlines of To-Dos or Details. Is there a property controlled through CSS that could remove this outline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the tab renderer being used for the `CTabFolder`. For the standard I don't think you can change this.

Using the tab renderer used by Eclipse there are a number of values you can set:

```
CTabFolder
{
    swt-tab-renderer: url('bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.CTabRendering');
    swt-unselected-tabs-color:  white white white 100% 100%;
    swt-selected-tab-fill: white;
    swt-outer-keyline-color: white;
    swt-tab-outline: white;
    swt-shadow-visible: false;
    swt-simple: true;
    swt-tab-height: 22px;
    swt-selected-tabs-background: white white 100%;
    swt-shadow-color: white;
}
```

`swt-tab-renderer` sets the tab renderer to be use.
I think `swt-tab-outline` sets the tab outline, but you may have to play with the others to get something consistent.